# Como insertar texto en la etiqueta <p> con SELENIUM

Tags: html, python, web, selenium-webdriver, web-scrapping

Gente necesito de su ayuda. Quiero insertar texto dentro de una caja de texto con selenium, pero no lo he logrado. Les comparto el codigo para

´´´´

```
 # Ingresa el nombre del primer contacto en el campo
             input_field.send_keys(contact_name)
             time.sleep(5)
             # Espera un momento para que aparezcan las sugerencias, si es necesario
             # Luego, presiona Enter para seleccionar la sugerencia (ajusta según necesites)
             input_field.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
             #input_field.send_keys(message)
             # Encuentra el elemento <p> dentro del campo de entrada
             time.sleep(5)
             
             div_text =  self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[starts-with(@class, 'msg-form__contenteditable')]")
             div_text.click()
             time.sleep(2)

             p_element = div_text.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "p")
             #p_element.click()
             time.sleep(2)
             # Inserta el mensaje dentro del elemento <p>
             p_element.send_keys("testing")
```

Ya intente ubicarlo por posicion pero el resultado es el mismo. no se puede insertar texto dentro de la etiqueta **p**

Este es el codigo HTML
´´´´

```
<div class="msg-form__msg-content-container--scrollable scrollable relative">
    <div class="flex-grow-1 relative">
<!---->  <div class="msg-form__contenteditable t-14 t-black--light t-normal flex-grow-1 full-height notranslate
      
      " contenteditable="true" role="textbox" aria-multiline="true" aria-label="Escribe un mensaje…"><p></p></div>

    <div aria-hidden="true" class="
        t-14 t-black--light t-normal" data-placeholder="Escribe un mensaje…">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: El método `send_keys` sirve para enviar pulsaciones de teclado, dicho de otro modo simula el presionar una tecla y para cambiar el DOM no se hace de esa forma, lo tienes que hacer con javascript

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda amigo. Te comento que si me funcionó